# Can the Same CA certificate be used with different types of WebServers?

Tags: ssl-certificate

I have developed a POC using Python, and am hosting it with the tornado webserver in our Intranet. I have been asked to make this HTTPS, and hence I'm working on buying a CA backed certificate.

It is possible that we would be moving to a PHP based service some time over the next 6 months.

Would the CA certificate I buy now, be usable with Apache down the line, if the server, and the intranet URL remain the same?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as the DNS name your using to access the site remains the same, it will continue working. Remember that you'll also need to move the corresponding private key and (if present) certificate chain to the new server and configure apache accordingly.